# C++ struct array initialization

Tags: c++, arrays, struct, initialization, braces

This is ok:

```
int vec_1[3] = {1,2,3};
```

so what's wrong with

```
struct arrays{
  int x[3];
  int y[3];
  int z[3];
};
arrays vec_2;
vec_2.x = {1,2,3};
```

that gives:

> ```
> error: cannot convert ‘<brace-enclosed initializer list>’ to ‘int’ in assignment
> ```

I've read a lot of posts on this error but it's still not clear where the problem is.

Comment: Because it has already been created.

Comment: The second one is not valid C++.  Try this:  `int vec_1[3];` followed by `vec_1 = {1, 2, 3};` This also won't compile for the same reason.

Answer (score 5):

The first is initialization. The second is an attempt at assignment, but arrays aren't assignable.

You could do something like:

```
arrays vec_2 = {{1,2,3}, {3,4,5}, {4,5,6}};
```

If you only want to initialize vec_2.x, then you can just leave out the rest of the initializers:

```
 arrays vec_2 = {1,2,3};
```

In this case, the rest of `vec_2` will be initialized to contain zeros.

While you have to include at least one set of braces around the initializers, you don't have to include the "inner" ones if you don't want to. Including them can give you a little extra flexibility though. For example, if you wanted to initialize the first two items in vec_2.x and the first one in vec_2.y, you could use:

```
arrays vec_2 = {{1,2}, {3}};
```

In this case, you'll get `vec_2` set as if you'd used `{1, 2, 0, 3, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0};` as the initializer.

Comment: I would have expected C++11 to allow `x={1,2,3}`, but it doesn't ([expr.ass] 5.17/9). Yet another reason to prefer `std::array`. Raw arrays just have too poor a design.

Answer (score 3):

This is assignment, not initialization:

```
arrays vec_2;
vec_2.x = {1,2,3};
```

Use the following, which is equivalent to what you were attempting:

```
arrays vec_2 = { {1, 2, 3 } };
```

If you want to provide values for `y` and `z` also:

```
arrays vec_2 = { {1,2,3}, // x
                 {4,5,6}, // y
                 {7,8,9}  // z
               };
```

Answer (score 2):

```
arrays vec_2;
vec_2.x = {1,2,3};
```

As the error message says, the second line is *assignment*, not *initialization*. They're two different things.

You need to do this:

```
arrays vec_2 = {
      {1,2,3}, //initializes x 
      {5,6,7}, //initializes y
      {7,8,9}, //initializes z 
};
```

Note that `,` is allowed after the last inner-brace! (i.e `{7,8,9},` <-- allowed). Such trailing comma is usually helpful for generated code: you can add another line, without caring about comma, neither do you need to consider any special case for the last line.

Answer (score 2):

```
int vec_1[3] = {1,2,3};
```

Despite what it looks like, this is not *assignment*, this is (effectively) a constructor call.  It constructs a array of `int` initialized to those values.

```
arrays vec_2;
```

This constructs a struct, and each of the member arrays with default values.

```
vec_2.x = {1,2,3};
```

You cannot assign arrays, and this member has already been constructed. The workaround is as such:

```
arrays vec_2 = { {1, 2, 3} };
```

which is the same thing  as

```
arrays vec_2 = { {1, 2, 3}, {0, 0, 0}, {0, 0, 0} };
```

Answer (score 1):

In the first example you are intializing the vector when you declare it.

In the second example, you are intializing twice (illegal), once when you declare the `arrays struct` and then again when you say `vec_2.x = {1,2,3}`